# separate ajax call for each page index change in datatable plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, datatables, webmethod

I am searching for the solution to this issue for more than a week which I could not found.here is my problem

we all know basic way to access ajax data paging through datatables plugin in Jquery. In this sample, all the data needed is retrieved and paging is done in browser memory. I do not need like this. Due to a huge amount of data, I am facing performance issues so we need a more sophisticated approach. That is separate ajax call for each page index change.

I have read [this link](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) which is for php so no work for me.

I read [this link](http://growingtech.blogspot.in/2012/06/ajax-data-paging-with-datatablesnet.html) which is MVC based so again no work for me.

Here is my code so how I can do this to modify my code

on A.aspx page

```
function showData(P1,P2) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'A.aspx/GetDataList',
    data: "{'P1':'" + P1+ "','P2':'" + P2+ "'}",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
   //make string of data here
   $('#example').html(table).dataTable();
   }
```

Now on A.aspx.cs

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static List<myclass> GetDataList(string P1, string P2)
{
    //make object of city class
    myclass cl = new myclass();
    cl.what = P1;
    cl.where = P2;
    return cl.GetDataList1();
```

}

here is my class function

```
public List<mycls> GetDataList1()
{

    try
    {

        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        DbCommand oCmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp");
         db.AddInParameter(oCmd, "@a", DbType.String, this.what);
         db.AddInParameter(oCmd, "@b", DbType.String, this.where);
        DataSet dsResult = db.ExecuteDataSet(oCmd);

            var query = from o in dsResult.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()

                        select new mycls
                        {
                            ID = o.Field<int>("ID"),
                            Name= o.Field<string>("Name")

                        };
            List<mycls> lstDisplay = new List<mycls>();
            lstDisplay.AddRange(query);
            return lstDisplay;


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
 }
```

Comment: i think datatable plugin do not support webmethod and pagination like what i want?